# magento - get attribute option label by store view

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Like the title, how can I get the attribute option value of a specific store view instead of the current store view ?

What I am trying to implement is something like this :

`public function getAttributeOptionValue($attributeCode, $attributeOptionLabel, $storeView)`

The attributeOptionLabel is the current attribute option label.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569039/attribute-options-labels-sorting-define-on-site-view-level/13570016#13570016

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simple! Ref [`Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute::getStoreLabel()` [link]](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute.php#L330):

```
<?php

include 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('default');

//Generic access
$eavConfig = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config');
/* @var $eavConfig Mage_Eav_Model_Config */

$eavAttribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute(
    Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY,  // 'catalog_product'; see db.eav_entity_type
    'description'                        // attribute code
);
/* @var $eavAttribute Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute */

Zend_Debug::dump(
    $eavAttribute->getStoreLabel('admin')
);


//For a given EAV entity-based model, the resource requires only the attribute
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(2);
/* @var $product Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */

$productAttribute = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('description');
/* @var $productAttribute Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute */

Zend_Debug::dump(
    $productAttribute->getStoreLabel('admin')
);

//It's also possible to get all labels:
Zend_Debug::dump(
    $productAttribute->getStoreLabels()
);
```