# MAGENTO 1.7.0.2 get collection of admin values of an attribute

Tags: magento

I need to get the collection of admin values of an attribute (color).
I used this function, but it return default store view value.

```
function getAttributes($option) {
//DEFINE MODEL
$catalog_products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product");

$attributes = Mage::getResourceModel("eav/entity_attribute_collection")
->setEntityTypeFilter($catalog_products->getResource()->getTypeId())
->addFieldToFilter("attribute_code", $option);

$attribute = $attributes->getFirstItem()->setEntity($catalog_products->getResource());

        foreach($attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(false) as $current)
            $collection[$current["value"]] = strtolower($current["label"]);

return $collection; }
```

So, for example, in this sequence of values
http://aruba.uriosweb.com/admin-values.png

it return:

[32] => acciaio
[388] => ago
[33] => algodo

but i would:

[32] => silver
[388] => ago
[33] => algodo

Comment: Look into this thread so you can get some idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683378/magento-get-attribute-option-label-by-store-view

Comment: It's seems return the admin Titles, but I need the options values.
Any ideas?

Comment: it fetch value store wise so if you want admin values then in store specification you have to define admin store

Comment: Can you write an example?

Comment: I need the "Admin" values instead "Default Store View" values.

Comment: Ok. I've solved with
`setCurrentStore(_id)` in `Mage::app("default")` call.